# sudo and fish: no credential caching

Tags: debian, ubuntu, sudo, fish

I use `fish` as my standard shell.
And I use `sudo` sometimes.

But I'm having problems with credential caching.

On an Ubuntu system, this works:

```
niklas@Niklas-Mobil~> sudo true
[sudo] password for niklas:
niklas@Niklas-Mobil~> sudo true
niklas@Niklas-Mobil~>
```

On a Debian system, this doesn't work:

```
niklas@ThinServer ~> sudo true
[sudo] password for niklas:
niklas@ThinServer ~> sudo true
[sudo] password for niklas:
niklas@ThinServer ~>
```

But on the same system as the same user with `bash`:

```
niklas@ThinServer:~$ sudo true
[sudo] password for niklas:
niklas@ThinServer:~$ sudo true
niklas@ThinServer:~$
```

It works using `dash`, too.

Why aren't the credentials cached when I'm using fish?
(And what can I do to solve this problem?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/sudoers`, add this line (or edit if it's existed):

```
Defaults !tty_tickets
```

`fish` somehow thinks command is from separated session. It's maybe due to tty's modification date as reported by stat is changing under `fish`. This was caused by fish's `futimes()` call

See more details:

- [fish issue #122](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/122)
- [Disable futimes()](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/1d54bff385240d9f7fd1d3ad6df56e74ddd5ef49)

Comment: Note, this issue was fixed in later version, but Debian hasn't cherrypicked it, Ubuntu did.

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, I'm using `Debian Wheezy`, which contains `fish` version 1.23.1 on its repo, too old.